# EncodingUtils no longer available in recent versions of Android

Tags: android, base64

It looks as if in recent versions of Android, EncodingUtils from the Apache package has been deprecated. We call `EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64")` a lot in our code which now needs to be upgraded. Is there any way we could achieve the end using a more modern way?

Comment: Have a look at Base64.encodeToString() : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte[], int)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use only `EncodingUtils` you can add the legacy dependency for Apache

```
android {
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your postData is a buffer it is enough to just call

```
  byte[] bytes = {...}
  String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // for UTF-8 encoding`
```